# apache redirect to SSL configured site

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, nginx

I am trying to setup a gitlab repository and I am quite new to the web server side of things. My setup is the following:

- I have an apache server which is running my main website on port 8080.
- I have the gitlab configured with SSL and Nginx and running on port 2443.

At the moment, the gitlab site can be accessed through `https://www.example.com:2443`.

What I would like to do is setup a redirect through my apache server where if someone comes to `http://www.example.com/gitlab` or `https://www.example.com/gitlab`, they get redirected to ``https://www.example.com:2443` (preferably without the web browser text field changing).

Could this be done easily with Apache? Also, since the redirect is to an SSL site, any special things we need to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the [redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive to your Apache VirtualHosts (8080 and 443).

```
Redirect permanent /gitlab https://www.example.com:2443
```